# How to organize multiple HashMaps?

Tags: java, hashmap, console-application

**Hello!** I'm trying to write as my first project a simple program, which would be able to test my knowledge of English words. The program is going to be similar to a paper version of dictionary. Right now managing program only with my testing unit of words (object *map*) is very simple and clear.

---

//Creating HashMap, which consists of words and their translated equivalents

```
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("0", "zero");
    map.put("1", "one");
    map.put("2", "two");
    map.put("3", "three");
    map.put("4", "four");
    map.put("5", "five");
    map.put("6", "six");
    map.put("7", "seven");
    map.put("8", "eight");
    map.put("9", "nine");
    map.put("10", "ten");
```

//User inputs integer from 1 to 100[%], which will determine number of words from base (HashMap) in the test

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    double goodAnswers = 0;
    int numberOfQuestions = scanner.nextInt();
    numberOfQuestions *= (double) map.size() / 100;
```

//Creating two arrays, first one which consists all keys from HashMap

```
    ArrayList<String> arrayInOrder = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
    ArrayList<String> arrayInDisorder = new ArrayList<String>();
```

//Filling a second array in a random manner

```
    int initialArraySize = arrayInOrder.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < initialArraySize; i++) {
        int j = new Random().nextInt(arrayInOrder.size());
        arrayInDisorder.add(arrayInOrder.get(j));
        arrayInOrder.remove(j);
    }
```

//Outputs a word (declared number of times) and waits for a user to input a translated word, then the program compares it with the value from the hashmap

```
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++) {
        System.out.println(arrayInDisorder.get(i));
        String input = scanner.next();
        if (input.equals(map.get(arrayInDisorder.get(i)))) {
            goodAnswers++;
        }
    }
```

//Outputs final result in %

```
    double result = 100 * goodAnswers / numberOfQuestions;
    System.out.println("Wynik: " + String.format("%.2f", result) + "%");
```

---

The difficulties start, however, when I want to give a user an option to choose from which units he wants to be tested. Let's say, now the program consists 3 HashMaps.

---

```
    HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map1.put("0", "zero");
    map1.put("1", "one");
    map1.put("2", "two");
    map1.put("3", "three");
    map1.put("4", "four");

    HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map2.put("5", "five");
    map2.put("6", "six");
    map2.put("7", "seven");
    map2.put("8", "eight");

    HashMap<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map3.put("9", "nine");
    map3.put("10", "ten");

    map2.putAll(map3);
    map1.putAll(map2);
```

---

There would be only 3 HashMaps now, and I could use method `putAll()`, but the problem is, that in the example above I merged all HashMaps and the functionality I want to add to my program is that ***user can choose from which units (*maps*) he/she wants to be tested.***

For example if the program would include 100 Hashmaps and a user just types `1, 7, 65` into the console, the program knows, that it have to merge 1st, 7th and 65th HashMap into a bigger one, which it is going to use as its 'main' `map` to test user's knowledge.

To sum up I would like to know how to merge these HashMaps which were chosen by a user into the single one (so my program will be able to use it), when he/she types them (HashMaps' names) into the console.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although your question is pretty well formulated, I'm unsure what your actual goal is (where do the two `HashMap`s come into play? I'm only seeing one) and thus would ask you to [edit] your question to make it a bit clearer so we can help you with your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem manifests here: `map1`

You have **more than** of some object. When you start giving them names like map1, map2, ... you are tying yourself to exactly those variables.

The concept to use instead: arrays, respectively List/ArrayList.

That is all there is to this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to you I recalled, that `Arrays` can contain other objects, for example `HashMaps`, so I came up with this:

---

```
    ArrayList<HashMap> motherArray = new ArrayList<HashMap>();

    motherArray.add(map1);
    motherArray.add(map2);
    motherArray.add(map3);
```

//Asking a user to choose number of units

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many maps do you want to include in your test?");
    int numberOfMaps = scanner.nextInt();
```

//Creating the HashMap, which will contain all HashMaps chosen by a user from Array created earlier

```
    HashMap<String, String> motherMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMaps; i++) {
        System.out.println("What are their numbers (indexes)?");
        int indexOfMap = scanner.nextInt();
        motherMap.putAll(motherArray.get(i));
    }
```

---

I'm not sure if it is precisely what you wanted to point out, but this solution seems to be working pretty well for me even if I decide to expand or increase the number of these maps.

**Thank you very much for your hint!**

Comment: You are very welcome. But just to be clear : ArrayList is NOT the same as arrays in Java. But picking ArrayList better fits to maps.